# Struts2 - Difference between struts.xml and struts-plugin.xml?

Tags: struts2, struts-config, struts2-config-browser

I have confusion about these files in *struts2.*
 Normally `struts.xml` file the core which has configuration in *struts1.* So I also thought of using struts.xml file.

But in my project already they put `struts2-config-browser-plugin.jar`, it has `struts-plugin.xml`. Just searched in Google and found that `struts-plugin.xml` is enough to run struts application.

Now I'm adding the `struts.xml` file, the application is not working.

1. Can I use both XML file in application?
2. If I remove the `struts2-config-browser-plugin.jar` , what are the changes need to add in `struts.xml` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three configuration files which are by default loaded by the framework (if they exist):

- `struts-default.xml` - included in struts2-core.jar, contains all basic configuration of the framework
- `struts-plugin.xml` - if plugin want to override some defaults or define its own settings (results, actions, etc)
- `struts.xml` - contains user defined configuration, mostly actions, results and custom stacks of interceptors

You should just use `struts.xml` and put all the configurations there.

Some notes about `struts-plugin.xml` - http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/plugins.html